# Remove JSON data in MariaDB database

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need to remove data named `money` in column `inventory` in table `users`.
The data is stored in `LONGTEXT` and is stored like this:

```json
[{"slot":1,"count":2,"metadata":[],"name":"clip"},{"slot":2,"count":1,"metadata":[],"name":"money"}]
```

In this example i would need the above data to change to this:

```json
[{"slot":1,"count":2,"metadata":[],"name":"clip"}]
```

I appreciate any answer to my problem.

I tried using:

```sql
UPDATE users
SET inventory = JSON_REMOVE(inventory, '$.[?(@.name == "money")]');
```

but this code removed the whole JSON and got NULL pointer instead.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/293864/is-it-possible-to-remove-a-json-array-element-by-value-in-mysql

Comment: May I ask _why_ you're storing JSON in an RDBMS in the first place? I like to think that this demonstrates why it's a important to normalzie your data in the first-place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution for a single row update (warning: don't run this if you want to update multiple rows, this will not give the expected result, see edit below) :

```sql
UPDATE USERS
SET inventory = (
    SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(
            'slot', tmp.slot,
            'count', tmp.count,
            'metadata', tmp.metadata,
            'name', tmp.name
        )
    )
    FROM JSON_TABLE(
        inventory,
        '$[*]' COLUMNS (
            slot INT PATH '$.slot',
            count INT PATH '$.count',
            metadata JSON PATH '$.metadata',
            name VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.name'
        )
    ) AS tmp
    WHERE tmp.name != 'money'
)
WHERE userId = 1;
```

Basically you use `JSON_ARRAYAGG` to build a new JSON array containing any element that are in the given JSON table (built with `JSON_TABLE`) but without the element containing the value you want to remove.

Of course adapt the `WHERE` clause of the `UPDATE` statement to your needs.

Before :

| userId | inventory |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"slot":1,"count":2,"metadata":[],"name":"clip"},{"slot":2,"count":1,"metadata":[],"name":"money"}] |

After:

| userId | inventory |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"slot": 1, "count": 2, "metadata": "[]", "name": "clip"}] |

Online executable example : https://onecompiler.com/mariadb/4266vw2w3

---

### **EDIT** :

For updating multiple rows, this is a little more complicated as you need to perform a subquery to generate the inventory data for each user.

This should do the job :

```sql
UPDATE USERS
JOIN (
    SELECT userId, JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(
            'slot', tmp.slot,
            'count', tmp.count,
            'metadata', tmp.metadata,
            'name', tmp.name
        )
    ) AS new_inventory
    FROM USERS
    JOIN JSON_TABLE(
        USERS.inventory,
        '$[*]' COLUMNS (
            slot INT PATH '$.slot',
            count INT PATH '$.count',
            metadata JSON PATH '$.metadata',
            name VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.name'
        )
    ) AS tmp ON tmp.name != 'money'
    GROUP BY userId
) AS updated_data ON USERS.userId = updated_data.userId
SET USERS.inventory = updated_data.new_inventory;
```

Before :

| userId | inventory |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"slot":1,"count":2,"metadata":[],"name":"clip"},{"slot":2,"count":1,"metadata":[],"name":"money"}] |
| 2 | [{"slot":3,"count":2,"metadata":[],"name":"clip"},{"slot":4,"count":1,"metadata":[],"name":"money"},{"slot":5,"count":1,"metadata":[],"name":"other"}] |
| 3 | [{"slot":6,"count":2,"metadata":[],"name":"clip"},{"slot":7,"count":1,"metadata":[],"name":"other"}] |

After:

| userId | inventory |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"slot": 1, "count": 2, "metadata": "[]", "name": "clip"}] |
| 2 | [{"slot": 3, "count": 2, "metadata": "[]", "name": "clip"}, {"slot": 5, "count": 1, "metadata": "[]", "name": "other"}] |
| 3 | [{"slot": 6, "count": 2, "metadata": "[]", "name": "clip"}, {"slot": 7, "count": 1, "metadata": "[]", "name": "other"}] |

Online executable example :
https://onecompiler.com/mariadb/4267ngy74

Note that the JSON is slightly reformatted, that happens because we are converting string to JSON object then write it back as string.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the asnwer, unfortunately i have a small problem. Every data in the column was copied from the first row to every other. I would be very thankfull if you could update the code so this wouldn't happen

Comment: Oh sorry, I simply followed your example in your question with a single row, but indeed this is a little more complicated for multiple rows, I updated my post for a possible solution. But the solution provided by @Flingo64 is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @j='[{"slot":1,"count":2,"metadata":[],"name":"clip"},{"slot":2,"count":1,"metadata":[],"name":"money"}]';
SELECT JSON_REMOVE(
    @j,
    substring_index(
        JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(@j, 'one', 'money', NULL, '$[*].name')),
        '.', 1
    )
) AS result
```